# Angular 5 Reactive Form Controll registerOnChange not calling the regestered method

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
  testing() {
    const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      testing: [''],
      resultingChanges: ['inital data']
    });
    const testing = formGroup.get('testing') as FormControl;
    testing.registerOnChange((value) => {
      formGroup.get('resultingChanges').setValue(value);
    });

    return formGroup;
  }
```

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
   <input type="text" formControlName="testing">
   <input type="text" formControlName="resultingChanges">
</form>
```

When I update the field tied to the testing it is not calling the regestredOnChange method.  But when I console.log the testing I can see the method registered in the _onChange property.

I want to change the value of resultingChanges based on the value of the testing.  I can do this in the component but I feel this logic should not be tied to a component but the formGroup. Does anyone know how to accomplish this without adding an onChange listener to the component and attaching this method there?

Comment: try `registerOnChange(this.updateAmenities.bind(this));`

Comment: it turns out the method is getting called but just not until I call formGroup.getRawValue();

Comment: The more i dig into it is seems that this is actually getting called when I Update the formGroup but not when the input field is changed.

Comment: I ended up finding the the issue.  The method gets called when you do amenitiesControl.setValue().  But when using a form input field, changes to the input field will not triger the ChangeListener because the reactive forms are not bound to the input fields like template forms.  Even when you call formGroup.getRawValue(), this will not trigger the method.  I consider this a huge flaw in reactive forms.  Here is a link to an article for more details:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13792

Answer (score 0):

Another approach ended up being the solution that is simple and scalable.

Simply create a directive that takes a formControl and update the formControl on change.

**Final Code:**
Form Builder:

```
  testing() {
    const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      testing: [''],
      resultingChanges: ['inital data']
    });
    const testing = formGroup.get('testing') as FormControl;
    testing.registerOnChange((value) => {
      formGroup.get('resultingChanges').setValue(value);
    });

    return formGroup;
  }
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  // When this field is updated it will not sync, it will behave exactly the same formGroups nativly interact with input fields
  <input type="text" formControlName="testing">
  // When this field is changed it will trigger the update method
  <input type="text" [formControl]="formGroup.get('testing')">
  <input type="text" formControlName="resultingChanges">
</form>
```

New Directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControl]'
})
export class FormControlSyncDirective {
  @Input('formControl') formControl: FormControl;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value']) onChange(newValue) {
    this.formControl.setValue(newValue);
  }
}
```

**Note:**
OnChange in the directive works like blur.  so if you want to update each keystroke then do a keyUp listener instead.